# How can I proportionally scale images to max-width?

Tags: html, css

In a UIWebView, I am using the CSS max-width property to scale images of unknown size to fill a space no larger than (but perhaps smaller than) 300 pixels wide. Some of the original images are larger, and others are smaller.

For now, I'm using the following CSS declaration, which scales the width correctly, but tends to blow out the height of larger images in the iOS WebView:

```
 img{
    max-width:300px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:0px;
 }
```

So the question is: What's the correct way to ensure the height scales proportionally along with the width?

*(Edited headline and tags to generalize solution. Thanks, matt!)*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
  img {
    max-width:300px; 
    height:auto
  }
```

This really has nothing to do with iOS or UIWebView - it's pure standard CSS.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it may be more general, but wanted to eliminate any false starts in case the issue was specific to mobile Safari. I've edited the question so it will be easier for others with similar issues to find.  (BTW, works great. Thanks!)

Comment: Only gotcha I can find is that if you're doing any sort of javascript while the page is still loading that checks page offsets, with height auto, the offset may change after the image loads if using lazy or deferred loading images.

Comment: It's kind of nuts, but this doesn't appear to work the other way around: `{ max-height: 300px; width: auto; }` squashes the image. >:-/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation points to add comments to the responses, so I'll list it here:

> img {
>      max-width:300px; 
>      height:auto
>    }

This line of CSS works on Chrome, Firefox and IE, but it only works on desktop browsers. As stated in the original question, the task is to set up proportional images in iOS; and on iOS Safari, this method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using pixel in the css, u can try to use percentage

Answer (score -1):

I believe The First anserwer is true
height:100%;